# Extract column from csv data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have `csv` data in `PHP` such as the following (note, it's text with new line characters in it, not a file):

```
$data = 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
    1,1,2014-12-10,5,1,2,0,2
    2,7,2014-12-09,9,0,,7,2';
```

How can I extract a column as an array that excludes the headers? For example, if I wanted to extract the 4th column, it would include 5 and 9.

**UPDATE**: I have tried

```
$te = array_column($data,'D');
```

and I get the error: `Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array,`

Comment: Read the data into an array with `fgetcsv()` and loop through the array extracting the column you want. For PHP 5.5+ you can use `array_column()` [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: no attempts? try `fgetcsv()`

Comment: Not sure if you're just new to PHP, but your first stop for most "how do i...?" questions should be the PHP manual.  If a lot of people have had to do it at some point, chances are there are three different functions for it built in.

Comment: Well maybe you could link if this is a duplicate otherwise seems like a reasonable question and a complete answer would be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse csv file php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930061/parse-csv-file-php)

Comment: To skip the headers, see [Read header of CSV separately](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18237576/319403)

Comment: Even closer match to your question: [PHP read in specific csv file column as an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12009023/319403)

Comment: @cHao however that has no accepted answer...

Comment: @Ghost see update for what I tried

Comment: Mostly because the OP kept having trouble.  The answer's not bad.

Comment: This is an XY question. You're asking about extracting a column, but it's far from clear what format the data is in, or how you intend to process it first. Your update shows a method of an unknown object that returns data in an unspecified format. Provide the proper context and you'll get a good answer. Ask a vague question and you'll get guesses.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, fair enough, originally I was more vague. See update. Data is a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this a comma delimited string, you could use `str_getcsv()` in this case:

```
// load the string and explode, then apply str_getcsv
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n", $request->getResponseBody()));
array_shift($data); // remove the header
$fourth_column = array();
foreach($data as $line) {
    if(!empty($line[3])) {
        $fourth_column[] = $line[3]; // indices start at zero
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am getting Notice: Undefined offset: 3 (on the line inside the foreach loop)

Comment: @CodeGuy this assumes `$data` in your is equivalent to `$request->getResponseBody()` is this correct? i just used that one you posted. heres a demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/dee32U. anyways `var_dump($line);` inside the foreach and tell me how it looks

Comment: Yes, $data is the same as $request->getResponseBody()

Comment: @CodeGuy then this should work just fine, look: `[3]=> string(1) "5"` first `$line`, second iteration: `[3]=> string(1) "9"`. check out the live demo above the comments i've already setup one

Comment: array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(10) "2014-12-10" [3]=> string(1) "5" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(1) "2" [6]=> string(1) "0" [7]=> string(1) "2" } array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "7" [2]=> string(10) "2014-12-09" [3]=> string(1) "9" [4]=> string(1) "0" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(1) "7" [7]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: Note: the loop runs more than twice...I think this is why there's an error. Any ideas?

Comment: @CodeGuy yes, its supposed to run twice. i `array_shift()` to remove the first row which is the header.

Comment: It runs three times and on the third time I think that's when the error gets generated...because there's not a 3rd line to extract out the 3rd column

Comment: Note: var_dump($data) gives: array(3) { [0]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(10) "2014-12-10" [3]=> string(1) "5" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(1) "2" [6]=> string(1) "0" [7]=> string(1) "2" } [1]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "7" [2]=> string(10) "2014-12-09" [3]=> string(1) "9" [4]=> string(1) "0" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(1) "7" [7]=> string(1) "2" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> NULL } }

Comment: `explode` will also give you the emptiness that follows the last row's newline.  You'll want to `array_pop` it off or something.

Comment: @CodeGuy just add a validation inside the foreach loop, checkout my revision

Comment: @cHao yeah most likely because of superfluous newlines causing empty rows

Comment: @Ghost: More because every row -- even the last -- has a newline at the end, per the definition of CSV...and `explode("\n", "a\n") === ['a', '']`.  You can either `trim` it off before splitting, or pop the last entry off after, but it's normal for it to be there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) to read each row as an array (discarding the first to skip headers). Then just keep the relevant column, e.g.:

```
$lines = preg_split("/(?:\r?\n|\r\n?)/", $data); // Split lines
array_shift($lines);                             // Discard header

$result = array();
foreach ($lines as $csv) {
    $row = str_getcsv($csv);
    $result[] = $row[3];
}
var_dump($result);
```

As per cHao suggestion in the comment below, if you need a more robust support of generic CSV data, you can dump the string to a virtual file and use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) instead (which already handles parsing of multiple lines of input correctly):

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fputs($fp, $data);
fseek($fp, 0);

$result = array();
fgetcsv($fp);
while (false != ($row = fgetcsv($fp))) {
    $result[] = $row[3];
}
fclose($fp);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Note: The CSV is a String, not a file. Would you mind modifying?

Comment: You can use `str_getcsv` to turn a line into an array.  Or, just write it to `php://temp`, rewind the file pointer, and you can still use `fgetcsv`.

Comment: Note, if there can have newlines in the data itself, a naïve "split by newlines" will break.  Not sure how well `fgetcsv` handles that either, though.

Comment: @cHao do you have a better idea?

Comment: @cHao good point, though the sample input didn't give me that feeling. If that was the case it would be a matter of adjusting the regex, since the CSV data should have some way to differentiate line ends from embedded newlines

Comment: It does.  Newlines are only row separators if they are not quoted.  Unfortunately, regexes rather suck at matching that.

Comment: @cHao oh, I wasn't aware, in that case resorting to in-memory/temporary files and `fgetcsv` as you suggested would be easier than writing our own parsing code (just tested it, `fgetcsv` does handle quoted newlines correctly).

Comment: Yeah. Like you said, though, it doesn't seem all that likely to apply in this case.  Just wanted to mention it for future readers :)